# arXiv, keyval and family_i

Tags: biblatex, key-value, arxiv

I'm trying to upload a long article with many macro files to arXiv, and I'm ending up with the following error:

`! Package keyval Error: family_i undefined.`

It seems that something is wrong with my `*.bbl`-file (which is required to be uploaded with the article by arXiv), or with arXiv's `biblatex` installation? But both arXiv and me are using TeXLive 2016, and it does compile on all of my machines, so the matter must be with arXiv? What is the real problem here?

Comment: The arxiv only has certain packages installed so the problem is almost certainly that it is missing, or has an old version of, something that you are using that you are using. We can't tell what the problem is from the information you have given. I suggest adding `\listfiles` to your document and then comparing your output with the output from the arxiv.

Comment: Quite probably your biblatex versions are different. You will have to find out their version and then setup your document so that it fits.

Comment: See [Biblatex and arxiv, error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/358831/35864). arXiv are running TeX live 2016, but certain packages are updated to a slightly later date than the release of TL 2016. I have reasons to believe they are running `biblatex` 3.7/Biber 2.7. You must have the exact same version. Check with `biber --version` and `\listfiles`.

Comment: Any news here? What versions of `biblatex` and Biber are you running?

Comment: @moewe, yes, indeed changing to `biblatex` 3.7 fixes the problem. I'm voting to close as a duplicate.