# Making the arXiv accept a BibTeX BBL (May 2018)

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, arxiv

I would like to upload a preprint to the arXiv with a bibliography. I prefer Biber personally, but I know from experience that if I upload a .bbl made with Biber, the arXiv will not interpret it correctly, due to an unrectifiable version mismatch. (For my current article, I tried it again, just to see if something had changed, and the compilation did work, but the compiled document did not show my citations or include a bibliography.)

So I produce a .bbl with BibTeX instead (**added in editing**: I achieve this by putting `\bibliographystyle{alphaurl}` in the preamble and `{\footnotesize\bibliography{mybib.bib} }` just before the end of my document, then compiling with `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`"), upload it, and compile. The error that finally makes the arXiv's compilation quit is the following:

```
! Package biblatex Error: File 'xxxxxxx.bbl' not created by biblatex.
```

Well, I was aware: I avoided BibLaTeX because I know the arXiv will only butcher it anyway. But it apparently doesn't like the BibTeX one because it's not BibLaTeX. **What can I do here?**

(Note to moderators: I know there is a family of variants on this question already in currency on this site, but as the arXiv's packages vary with time, so do the answers to the question(s). Nothing else I've found seen helps me as of right now.)

Comment: Can you explain how you produced the `.bbl` file? To successfully compile a document using `biblatex` on the arXiv you need the exact same version of `biblatex` that they are running (`biblatex` 3.7/Bibwe 2.7: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/358831/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415703/35864). In fact you can submit a `.bbl` file written by Biber as long as it was written by the correct version of Biber. A `.bbl` file written by BibTeX must also come from the same version of `biblatex` as on the arXiv. ...

Comment: ...  The fact that `biblatex.bst` is changed not as often as Biber's internals makes it more likely that a BibTeX-generated `.bbl` will conform with the version requirements of the arXiv than a Biber-generated one. But if you are using `biblatex` v3.8 or later both Biber and BibTeX should not work for you. So the only answer is: Get the versions of `biblatex` and Biber that the arXiv is running and compile your document using these versions.

Comment: The arXiv is currently using an updated TeX live 2016 if you don't have a freeze of that system available you have OK-ish chances of getting along fairly well with an un-updated TeX live 2017 system. You can install historic releases of TeX live from ftp://tug.org/texlive/historic/

Comment: I produced the .bbl file I'm trying to use now by putting \bibliographystyle{alphaurl} in the preamble and {\footnotesize\bibliography{mybib.bib} } just before the end of my document, and compiling with PDFLaTeX, BibTeX, PDFLaTeX, PDFLaTeX

Comment: To sum it up, you dropped using `biblatex` with `biber`.

Comment: Please edit that in to your question. A `.bbl` file produced that way can not be used by `biblatex` (as the message suggests). (Traditional) BibTeX and `biblatex` use `.bbl`s for different purposes. With traditional BibTeX the `.bbl` file contains the entire bibliography as it should be printed, with `biblatex` the `.bbl` file contains only a digested version of the `.bib` file, the information there is then used to produce the bibliography.

Comment: I am happy to modify the question, but I do not understand what you want me to add. I said that I was trying not to use `biblatex` and to upload a `bibtex`-produced `.bbl` instead. It wasn't my intention to have `biblatex` called to do anything, and thought not calling it as a package would be enough. I understand that it is trying to process this non-`biblatex`-produced `.bbl` with `biblatex`, but not why or how to avoid this.

Comment: I just wanted you to edit in the "I produced the .bbl file I'm trying to use now by putting \bibliographystyle{alphaurl} in the preamble and {\footnotesize\bibliography{mybib.bib} } just before the end of my document, and compiling with PDFLaTeX, BibTeX, PDFLaTeX, PDFLaTeX" comment so it does not get lost in the comment section. The information there is crucial to understanding what is going on and what you are doing.

Comment: I have two devices. On this one, the `biblatex` version is too old, and on the other, if I remember correctly, it is too new. They both are TeX Live running on Ubuntu. How can I update/downgrade?

Comment: I'll write something up, it may take a while, though.

Comment: I didn't understand @Johannes_B's comment. What I took out was `%\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee-alphabetic,sorting=nyvt]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{mybib.bib}` in the preamble and `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]` at the end of the document. Was this some sort of mistake?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_a_Bibliography

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**If you are looking for help with `biblatex` and Biber for arXiv uploads, have a look at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/wiki/biblatex-and-the-arXiv and [Biblatex and arxiv, error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/358831/35864) as well.**

**Overleaf users may be interested in https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/LaTeX_checklist_for_arXiv_submissions.**

---

There are several things going on here, so I think it is important to understand the big picture first.

## `biblatex` vs BibTeX - `biber` vs. `bibtex`

There is a difference between `bibtex` (the program/"backend") and "the BibTeX way of producing a bibliography". That distinction becomes relevant if `biblatex` is introduced into the equation. The "BibTeX way of producing a bibliography" is just one way to get a bibliography in LaTeX, other options include `biblatex` and the manual way with `thebibliography` (the [LaTeX Wikibook lists several ways to produce a bibliography in detail](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management), and also [in a short overview](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_Citations_and_Bibliographies)). The BibTeX way of producing a bibliography is of course tied to using `bibtex` (the program), a manual `thebibliography` needs no additional helper program, and `biblatex` can run with either its dedicated Biber backend (preferred) or with `bibtex`. Please read [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) for more explanations on this. For a great explanation of the roles of the backend (`bibtex` or Biber), see [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864).

## `.bbl` files and their differences between `biblatex` and BibTeX

The role that the `.bbl` file plays with `biblatex` and the BibTeX-way are similar, but `.bbl` files produced for the two possible ways differ significantly. If you use the BibTeX-way, the BibTeX run will produce a `.bbl` file that contains the bibliography exactly as it should appear in the document, it is formatted and sorted. With `biblatex` the `.bbl` file does not contain the finished bibliography, instead it contains the data of the entries in a format digestible by LaTeX along with a few bits and pieces of extra information that is not present in the `.bib` file (disambiguation, automatically calculated labels, ...); the entries are also sorted.
A `.bbl` file created for the BibTeX way of making bibliographies is completely incompatible with the `.bbl` file produced for `biblatex` (either by `bibtex` or Biber).

You are using `biblatex` with Biber as backend (a good choice), your document (drawing from the comments) looks roughly like

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee-alphabetic,sorting=nyvt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

A document like this will always expect a `.bbl` file as produced by Biber. Even if you change `backend=biber` to `backend=bibtex`, the `.bbl` file must have been created by BibTeX for use with `biblatex`, it can't come from a document that does not use `biblatex`. The `.bbl` file produced for

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\bibliographystyle{alphaurl}
\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

can not be used for `biblatex`.

## What the error message is about

Whatever you do, you can't mix and match between those two approaches on your local machine and the arXiv version. This is why you are seeing the error message

> ```
> ! Package biblatex Error: File 'xxxxxxx.bbl' not created by biblatex.
> ```

The paper you submitted to the arXiv uses `biblatex` (with Biber!), while the `.bbl` you submitted with it was produced by `bibtex` for the BibTeX way of creating bibliographies.

## Submitting the correct `.bbl` to the arXiv

### BibTeX

If you go with the BibTeX-way you can simply upload the `.bbl` to the arXiv and you are good - of course the paper you upload must then also use the BibTeX-way, so it should look like the second code example and not like the first.

### `biblatex`

If you use `biblatex` you will have to make sure that the `.bbl` you upload is compatible with the version of `biblatex` and Biber on the arXiv (at present that is `biblatex` 3.7 and Biber 2.7, see [Biblatex and arxiv, error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/358831/35864) and [Which biblatex/biber version produces BBL format 2.8?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415703/35864)) - again, naturally the `.tex` file you upload must use `biblatex` as well. In practice that means that you have to run the same versions of `biblatex` and Biber on your local machine that the arXiv are running. See [Matching biblatex in two machines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/410512/35864) for an explanation why that is necessary.

If you use `biblatex` it is not that relevant for the arXiv whether you use `bibtex` or Biber as backend. While the general rule is that using the `bibtex` backend offers fewer features and is more stable (in terms of new features) than Biber, the relevant changes to the `.bbl` file version normally affect both `bibtex` and Biber. The fact that `biblatex.bst` in general is quite stable (many new features require Biber) could be reason to hope that using `bibtex` as backend may be a way to avoid `.bbl` version incompatibilities. Normally, however, if changes are required to the `.bbl` format, `biblatex.bst` must change as well (sometimes this is forgotten and can cause other issue, but you should not rely on the forgetfulness of the developers). So you should not have a significant advantage in using `backend=bibtex` here, we will therefore stick to `backend=biber`.

#### Get the correct system

So you need to install the correct version of `biblatex` and Biber (along with all the dependencies) on your system. The arXiv is running a TeX live 2016 system *with updated packages*, if you did not save a snapshot of a TeX live 2016 system at the time the arXiv updated their system, there is little chance you are going to be able to recreate the exact system they are running. **As far as `biblatex` and Biber are concerned, you should be good with an un-updated TeX live 2017.** You can get historic TeX live releases from ftp://tug.org/texlive/historic/ and [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864) explains how to install such a system (see also [TeX Archaeology - Installing historic/old TeX Live Releases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258478/35864)). Do not install this system over you current system, it is possible to install several TeX live versions alongside each other without interference, see [Using two installs of texlive in parallel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/259107/35864).

Comment: Thank you. I admit I hadn't ever understood why `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` was an option. What puzzles me about this is that I understood enough of this to remove overt reference to `biblatex` from my document, as I said in comments, so I believe it already does look like your second parody document. At least, I have been able to make the arXiv accept such a BibTeX-produced `.bbl` before by similar methods. I wasn't sure if something had changed or I'd just missed something.

Comment: @jdc Hope it has become a bit clearer now. Let me know if you the answer could be improved (and also when you succeed to convince the arXiv to accept your files).

Comment: I've figured out what it was I did. It was something stupid. I kept replacing the `.bbl` and the `.tex`, but there also was a `.sty` file I foolishly failed to upload the revised version of, so no wonder. It accepted the BibTeX-produced `.bbl` when I was done. I don't have enough room on this device for a parallel one-purpose TeX Live distribution, so I'll save your `biblatex` answer for the other computer. Many thanks.