# Can a LaTeX file include the BibTeX file?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

Is there a way to include the BibTeX content in the LaTeX file?

The issue came up during a revision submission to a journal. I could submit a new main file but I did not see a way of submitting a new BibTeX file. So the natural question was if I can combine them into a single file

Comment: You can use the `filecontents` environment (and possibly the `filecontents` package).

Comment: While `filecontents` does technically embed the `.bib` file in the `.tex` file this is rarely what journals want on submission. With BibTeX-based bibliographies they usually want you to copy the `.bbl` into the actual `.tex` file as described in https://www.overleaf.com/help/219. For `biblatex` that won't work as easily, it is technically possible but rarely works for journal submissions, most publishers can't accept `biblatex` anyway, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/biblatex-submitting-to-a-journal?rq=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## `filecontents`

[Phelype Oleinik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134574/phelype-oleinik) mentions the `filecontents` environment [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454035/can-a-latex-file-include-the-bibtex-file#comment1141791_454035) and purely from the title of your question I would have said that is what you are looking for (assuming that BibTeX file means `.bib` file).

`filecontents` can be used to include an arbitrary file in a `.tex` file. That file will be written into the working directory (usually the folder where your main `.tex` file lives), if it does not exist already (if your LaTeX is new enough, you can use the optional argument to pass `force` or `overwrite` to the environment to make LaTeX overwrite an existing file with that name - use this option carefully) when TeX compiles the `.tex` file.

So

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year    = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Will produce a `.bib` file with the same name as the `.tex` file and that file can then be used to produce the bibliography.

`filecontents` is *extremely* useful if you want to provide self-contained files for other people for testing, it is also very good for MWEs on this site. But it is usually not what publishers want when they ask you to submit the bibliography in your `.tex` file. This is what the body of your question seems to be about. Publishers then usually talk about the `.bbl` file.

## `.bbl` files for BibTeX-based bibliographies

When you compile the example from above with LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX you get a document with a fully working bibliography. The key to that bibliography is the `.bbl` file that is produced by the BibTeX run. You can learn more about it at [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864), but in a nutshell the `.bbl` file contains the bibliography in a format that is ready to typeset for LaTeX in a `thebibliography` environment that one could also produce manually.

The `.bbl` file for the example above contains (amongst others, I shortened it a bit)

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem[Appleby(1980)]{appleby}
Humphrey Appleby.
\newblock \emph{On the Importance of the Civil Service}.
\newblock 1980.
\end{thebibliography}
```

that code can be directly typeset by LaTeX.

Indeed, if you replace the the line

```
\bibliography{\jobname}
```

from the example above with the entire contents of the `.bbl` and throw out the `filecontents` to obtain

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi

\bibitem[Appleby(1980)]{appleby}
Humphrey Appleby.
\newblock \emph{On the Importance of the Civil Service}.
\newblock 1980.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

you get a document that can be compiled with LaTeX alone to produce the same document with a bibliography and working citations.

This is what many publishers would like you to submit, since that is one document that contains all typesettable material directly and does not require additional runs of auxiliary tools like BibTeX. See also https://www.overleaf.com/help/219.

Some journals may not need you to copy the contents of the `.bbl` file into the `.tex` file directly and instead ask you to submit the `.tex` and `.bbl` file together, but they rarely want the `.bib` file.

## `.bbl` files for `biblatex`

`.bbl` files for `biblatex` do not contain ready-to-typeset TeX code, instead they contain the extended and sorted raw data in a format that is easier to digest for LaTeX than the `.bib` files The formatting still has to be done on the `biblatex` side. That means that it is not as easy to just copy and paste the `.bbl` contents.

It is possible to include a `biblatex`-`.bbl` into a  `.tex` as explained in [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/biblatex-submitting-to-a-journal?rq=1), but that is rarely what journals want or need. For one the `.bbl` file is intimately tied to a specific version of `biblatex` (and Biber), which means that your version and your publisher's version of the software must be the same. Secondly, not many publishers can deal with `biblatex` anyway as it requires a different workflow than BibTeX-based bibliographies, so it is unlikely that they can accept a submission even if you include the `.bbl` file and you have matching versions.

People submitting to the arXiv, which allows `biblatex` submissions, often have version problems and need to find old versions of `biblatex` and Biber to make things work. See [Making the arXiv accept a BibTeX BBL (May 2018)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429436/35864).