# arXiv does not compile my bibliography

Tags: biblatex, arxiv

During the submission process on arXiv, arXiv does not compile my bibliography. Some lines of its output:

```
Processing Status: Succeeded with warnings. We recommend that you inspect the log (see below).
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'xxx' on page 22 undefined on input line 1453.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 1601.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
[verbose]: WARNING: Reached max number of passes, possibly failed to get CROSS-REFERENCES right.
```

And indeed, in the generated pdf, references do not appear.  But it works correctly on my computer. Do you have any idea why arXiv fails ? My tex file is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
...
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
...
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{xxx.bib}
...
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{xxx.bib}
...
\begin{document}
...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I tried removing the `[overwrite]` but the result stays the same.  I do not have a \usepackage{hyperref}, even in a commented line, or other "hyper" or "ref" package.   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Arxiv has never supported running external programmes like bibtex or biber. Normally when using bibtex arxiv ask the author to include the generated bbl foøile from the authors pc. Since biblatex is **very** version dependent that might not work with biblatex. Might be an idea to see if arxiv it self has any information for biblatex users

Comment: As daleif says: arXiv don't run external tools, so you have to upload the `.bbl` file, not the `.bib` file. The `.bbl` file has tight version dependencies with your `biblatex` package version, so you need to make sure that your `biblatex` version and the arXiv version are compatible. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429436/35864 and linked posts.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. @moewe: it worked ! so if you make your comment as an answer (which it is), I'll accept it.

Comment: @daleif Do you want to type up a quick answer here?

Comment: @moewe not at a real pc for the rest of the week, also your comment match biblatex much better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif) [points out in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634736/arxiv-does-not-compile-my-bibliography#comment1582387_634736) arXiv does not run external tools like BibTeX or Biber on your document. They only run LaTeX. So you need to upload the bibliography data in such a way that only a LaTeX run is needed. This can usually be achieved by uploading the `.bbl` file.

With `biblatex` the format  of the `.bbl` file is tied to the version of `biblatex`, so you need to make sure that your version of `biblatex` is compatible with the version of `biblatex` on the arXiv. This is explained in more detail at [Making the arXiv accept a BibTeX BBL (May 2018)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429436/35864) and linked posts (it should be noted that the arXiv occasionally update its TeX live, so the information there might become outdated at some point).